# How do I activate NavMesh in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, navmesh

I'm making a car type game, and wanted to use NavMesh to "control" my car.

I was wondering how exactly to activate it, as I can't find a straightforward answer anywhere else.

Comment: Read through this section of the unity manual, [Navigation & Pathfinding](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Navigation.html).  It is unclear what you mean by "activate it", perhaps these docs will answer that.  Maybe you are confusing `NavMesh` with `NavMeshAgent`?

Answer (score 0):

Its something like this

1. You add Navmesh agent to the player that will move on the Navmesh.
2. Add Navmesh obstacles.
3. Generate Navmesh and use script to set destination of the agent to move it.

This [tutorial](https://vionixstudio.com/2021/08/17/make-enemy-ai-in-unity/) might be helpful to you.